# Nil found while unwrapping optional

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a chat application but the issue that is happening to me is that I am trying to get the cell in the tableview to show the displayname of the user. But for some reason it keeps saying that there is a nil. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my struct or the way I am referencing the data.

**Struct**

```
struct User {
    let name: String!
    let uid: String!
}
```

**Table View Cell**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    // **** Crash is on the following line ****
    let nameTxtField = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    nameTxtField.text = users[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
```

**Table View viewDidload**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").child(uid!).queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let name = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["name"] as? String ?? ""

        let uid = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["uid"] as? String ?? ""

        self.users.append(User(name: name, uid: uid))

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Database Structure**
[image]

Comment: Don't use `viewWithTag` - Create a proper `UITableViewCell` subclass so that you can reference your label via a property.  Which line does it complain about the `nil` on?  Split up your lines that access the firebase result and don't use `NSDictionary`

Comment: Also, I would strongly suggest that you update your struct so that `name` and `uid` are either optionals or not.  Don't use implicitly unwrapped optionals

Comment: @Paulw11 it complains at this line `let nameTxtField = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel` 
I have also gone ahead and changed structs to optionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in this row:

```
let nameTxtField = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
```

The cell is not loaded from storyboard yet, so `cell.viewWithTag(1)` is nil. Nil + ! = crash.

Usually I fill cells with following algorithm:

1. Create a separate class for cells of every type
2. Implement method `customizeUI()` to fill necessary UI controls on the cell
3. Add iVar of the data type to be shown in this cell and call customizeUI() in it's setter.

   var item: HistoryItem? {
       didSet {
          customizeUI()
       }
   }

This method checks if the cell is already loaded:

```
func customizeUI() {
    guard let label = self.nameLabel else {
        return
    }
    // Fill UI controlls
    label.text = item.name
    ...
}
```

Also this method must be called in cells `awakeFromNib()` method.

And finally, in your `cellAt...` method you must write something like `cell.item = dataItem` instead of filling your UI controls directly.

Answer (score 1):

The `queryOrderedBy...` and `.childAdded` are only needed when you want to get a number of children from a list based on some condition. But in your case you know the exact path of the child node, so you don't need the query.

So you're performing a direct read, but are using `queryOrderedByKey()` and `.childAdded`. That means that your closure gets called with each child under `/users/rPJSO...`, once for each individual property: `email`, `name`, `password`, `uid`. And since there's no `name` property **under** any of these, the lookup for that will return `nil`.

The solution is pretty simple: remove the `queryOrderedByKey` and listen for `.value`:

```
ref.child("users").child(uid!).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
  ...
```

The rest of your code can stay the same.

Comment: Based on the updated info, none of this relates to the actual error.

Comment: Ah... thanks for catching. Ah, the wonders of an MCVE. This is still a problem with the code shared though, so I'm leaving it for OP.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment you are getting a crash on the line

```
let nameTxtField = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
```

This means that `viewWithTag(1)` is either returning `nil` or something other than a `UILabel`.  Either you haven't set the tag of the label to 1 or you have more than one UI element with tag 1 (`viewWithTag` will return the first view in the hierarchy with that tag).

You should create an appropriate `UITableViewCell` subclass and link your `UILabel` to a property on that class.  Then you can say something like:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
cell.nameTxtField.text = users[indexPath.row].name
```

A couple of other comments; You should try and eliminate as many ! as possible.

- Your struct's properties should either be optionals or non-optionals, not implicitly unwrapped optionals.

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    let uid: String
}
```

- You should retrieve the `uid` with a `guard` statement rather than force-unwrapping it later
- Your code for obtaining the user will be clearer if you spread it over a few lines
- Avoid the use of `NS...` objects in Swift
- I also note Frank's answer regarding the way you are accessing Firebase, but I don't know enough about Firebase to know whether that is an issue or not;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").child(uid).queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        guard let result = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
            return
        }

        let name = (result["name"] as? String) ?? ""

        let uid = (result["uid"] as? String) ?? ""

        self.users.append(User(name: name, uid: uid))

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```